# Enrich Json with new elements not working for me .Please guide

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Enrich Json with new elements not working for me .Please guide.

Input request :

```
 {
        "id" : "1",     
        "make" : "NAHB"
    }
```

I created wso2 flow named eg1.xml . I am trying to enrich the incoming json request with new element "name"

processing xml: (eg1.xml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <api context="/eg1" name="eg1" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/hi">
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full"/>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property expression="//jsonObject" name="msg1"/>
                </log>
                <enrich description="">
                    <source clone="true" type="inline">
                        <name xmlns="">Home</name>
                    </source>
                    <target action="child" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
                </enrich>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property expression="//jsonObject" name="msg2"/>
                </log>
                <log level="full"/>
                <respond/>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence/>
            <faultSequence/>
        </resource>
    </api>
```

current output :

```
 {
        "id" : "1",     
        "make" : "NAHB"
    }
```

Desired output :

```
 {
        "id" : "1",     
        "make" : "NAHB"
        "name" : "Home"
    }
```

logger output :

Logger1 output(log level full) : 
LogMediator To: /eg1/hi, MessageID: urn:uuid:2f627daf-ac9c-4492-84ea-2736670724e8, Direction: request, Payload:

```
   {
        "id": "1",
        "make": "NAHB"
    }
```

Logger2 output :
LogMediator msg1 =

```
 <jsonObject>
        <id>1</id>
        <make>NAHB</make>
    </jsonObject>
```

Logger3 output :
LogMediator msg2 =

```
 <jsonObject>
        <id>1</id>
        <make>NAHB</make>
        <name>Home</name>
    </jsonObject>
```

Logger4 output(log level full) : 
LogMediator To: /eg1/hi, MessageID: urn:uuid:2f627daf-ac9c-4492-84ea-2736670724e8, Direction: request, Payload:

{
    "id": "1",
    "make": "NAHB"
}

Postman output :

```
 {
        "id": "1",
        "make": "NAHB"
    }
```

Regards,
Aditya

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the response back to body

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="eg1" context="/eg1">
<resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/hi">
  <inSequence>
     <log level="full"/>
     <log level="custom">
        <property name="msg1" expression="//jsonObject"/>
     </log>
     <enrich description="">
        <source type="inline" clone="true">
           <name xmlns="">Home</name>
        </source>
        <target action="child" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
     </enrich>
     <log level="full">
        <property name="msg2" expression="//jsonObject"/>
     </log>
     <enrich>
        <source clone="true" xpath="//jsonObject"/>
        <target type="body"/>
     </enrich>
     <log level="full"/>
     <respond/>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence/>
  <faultSequence/>
```

I have tried this API

Request

```
 {
    "id" : "1",     
    "make" : "NAHB"
}
```

Response

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "make": "NAHB",
   "name": "Home"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 ways to do it:

1. Enrich mediator: as described in the other answers
2. Payload Factory mediator: will require adding all the parameters in the arguments unless the new element will be in a separate sub element
3. Script mediator:

   ```
                <script language="js">
                <![CDATA[
                    var payload = mc.getProperty('payloadProperty'); // if original json is in property. If received as payload use: mc.getPayloadJSON();
                   var json =  JSON.parse(payload);
                    var newElement = mc.getProperty('newElement'); // get the value of the new element
                    json.newElementName = newElement; // define it (newElementName not present in the json in the original payload
                    mc.setPayloadJSON(json); // put the result back as payload. Optional: read it in a property as done below if needed, otherwise just call the next service
               ]]>
           </script>
           <property expression="json-eval($)" name="json" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
   ```